# React native form submit webview reloads to the same page

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I'm integrating ccAvenue payment gateway to my reactnative application. i am sending html string which submits the form and redirects to the action.

```
<WebView
       ref="webview"
       html={{html: htmlString}}
       onNavigationStateChange={ e => {
          console.log('e', e);
       }}
   />
```

- It opens ccAvenue payment gateway, but after successful submission of details, it again executes htmlString, submits form and it will be redirected to same page again.

Comment: can you please provide the documentation which you followed to implement ccavenue payment gateway for react native

Answer (score 0):

**That was from ccAvenue.**

- i was not inserting the address data and so it was reloading the same page and not resolving.

-- **Happy Coding... (▀̿Ĺ̯▀̿ ̿)**